# Jquery ajax json response not showing

Tags: ajax, jquery, json

Hey all my code is as follows:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "master.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "called": "REG",
            "fname": $("#FName").val()                              
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, responseText, textStatus){
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log("good: " + response);
        console.log("good3: " + textStatus);
        console.log("good3: " + responseText);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("error: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

And my master.php has:

```
<?php
$called = $_POST['called'];

if ($called == 'REG') {
    $json = array('good' => 'the value here');
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

The console output i get is this:

*good: null form.php:102*

*good3: [object Object] form.php:103*

*good3: success*

What would i be missing?

Comment: Why are you setting the contentType in the `$.ajax()` call? Just let it send the parameters in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the POST method, but accessing the $_GET array in the PHP script

Comment: Changed it to POST but still getting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `jQuery.parseJSON()` in the success function. When you specify `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery does this automatically for you.